# nslookup returning secondary IP of a listener (different subnet)

Tags: sql-server-2014, availability-groups, listener

I'm pretty confused about this issue.

We noticed that we sometimes receive some errors from the app servers causing timeouts.

after a lot of digging, we discovered that sometimes when using a listener that has a secondary IP from a different subnet, sometimes this is the IP returned to connect.

we could prove that by running `nslookup <listener>` multiple times, and sometimes it returns the second IP of the listener. even on the cluster failover manager we see that the IP is offline.

we know that there's an option in the cluster configuration to not allow this scondary IP to be used, but why does that happen? if there's 2 ips in a listener, why sometimes it brings the second  one when the second is in a different subnet?does this happen when we have 2 ips of the same subnet?

obviously, when that happens the app fails because it's pointing to a ASYNC replica.

by unchecking that box, I know this will not happen again but I'm curious if this is a know behaviour.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you’re using the default cluster settings, `RegisterAllProvidersIP = 1`, SQL Server will register all listener IP address in DNS, not just the active one. As such, DNS will return all registered IP addresses of the listener during all lookup requests, not just the one of a specific subnet. If the client application is multi-subnet aware, it will try all IP addresses returned and establish a connection to the one that is listening.

If the client is not multi-subnet aware (which it sounds like yours is not), it will try the first IP address returned by DNS, and if it fails to connect, it will never try the additional IP addresses. In this case, you should update the cluster setting to `RegisterAllProvidersIP = 0`. Doing so forces the cluster to only register the active IP address for the listener. However, you would also want to consider reducing the TTL so the IP does not remain cached on clients for a longer period of time than necessary following a failover to another subnet.